# How to send String data with formdata in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnUpdate").click(function(){
        alert($("#frm_data").serialize());
        var formData = new FormData($("#frm_data")[0]);
        var Desc= CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();

        $("#btnUpdate").attr('value', 'Please Wait...');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'update_job.php',
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType:false,
            processData:false,
            type: 'post',
            success: function(response)
            {
                $("#btnUpdate").attr('value', 'Update');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
})
</script>
```

i use ckeditor for textarea field. but its can update value with new value, so i want to use another way with send textarea value with form data.
so how to send Desc data with fromData. in ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can use the `append()` method of `FormData` to add whatever additional information you require:

```
$("#btnUpdate").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $btn = $(this).attr('value', 'Please Wait...');
    var formData = new FormData($("#frm_data")[0]);
    formData.append('desc', CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData());

    $.ajax({
        url: 'update_job.php',    
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'post',
        success: function(response) {    
            $btn.attr('value', 'Update');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: var formData = new FormData($("#frm_data")[0]);
var data = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();
formData.append('desc',data);

Comment: That would work too. Are you having problems with it?